# how to add a div for dynamic table Td (not Th)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
 function table() {
            var body = document.body,
                     tbl = document.createElement('table'),
                     tableId = document.createAttribute('id');
            tableId.value = "table";
            tbl.setAttributeNode(tableId);
            tbl.className = 'table2';
            var id = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                var tr = tbl.insertRow();
                tr.setAttribute("data-id", i, 0);

                for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                    var td = tr.insertCell();
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));

                    td.id = "td" + id ;
                    id++;
                }

            }
            
           
            $(".middletablediv").append(tbl);
           
        };
        table();
```

i have dynamic table which contain td and th  i add div for table td but it also effect the th .i don't want that div in th i want div only in div

```js
$('tr:first-child').children('td').replaceWith(function(i, html) {
  return '<th>' + html + '</th>';
});
```

this code is used for change first row td into th
and

```js
$('#table td').wrapInner('<div class="tddivcolor divtime" />');
```

this for adding class to td

Comment: what you want is a bit unclear why do you have replace td with th? what do you really want?

Comment: you want to replace all the tds in the table or particular row and particular column

Comment: i want my first table row td as th.then i want add  a div in other td

Comment: Can you share a table sample as well

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vt9fy02e/2/ ?

Comment: i add the code for table here

Comment: what is tablegraph?

Comment: sorry its not table graph it is table .thats my editing mistake

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vt9fy02e/3/

Comment: The only reason I could see is the order of execution, make sure the th code is executed first then the wrapping code

Comment: Another choice is `$('#table tr:not(:first-child) td').wrapInner('<div class="tddivcolor divtime" />');`

Comment: @Arun p johny thanks it's now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I could see is the order of your script execution.

If you are running the wrapping code first then the `td`->`td` conversion code then the `div`s will get added to the first row also.

So one solution is to fix the order and move the `th`  conversion code first.

If that is not possible then you can exclude the first row from wrapping

```
$('#table tr:not(:first-child) td').wrapInner('<div class="tddivcolor divtime" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific, try to use append if it works for you.

```
<table><tr><td>...
```

this not be the exact answer you need, but might lead to proper direction.

like where you want to put div, then try this, i used this to my selector class to create 'div'

```
$("#SelectorID").append("<div class= EmpList id=" + empID + ">" + selectedList[empID] + " <span class='close'>&times;</Span> </div>");
```